# Installing Ubuntu Desktop on server with only system management tools in it?

Tags: unity, server, system-installation, ubuntu-minimal

I'd like to install ubuntu-desktop on the server edition of Ubuntu 4.04 LST. The default installation is bloated, with too many packages in it. So I tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

This however, installed a desktop version with nothing on it at all. Not even a power button on the upper taskbar, or a way to configure networking on the desktop, or a disk usage utility.

Is there a reasonable installation option, made for humans who just want a complete desktop installation with no **extra** software like OpenOffice or Thunderbird?

I could not find a way to get a complete OS installed without all the other stuff that I don't need..

If not, then how can I know which packages to install to get these basic features into the minimal desktop? Searching on the dash gave me nothing other than online pages.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these should cover what you want:

- Some recommended packages for ubuntu-desktop (`apt-cache depends ubuntu-desktop` to see complete list):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility gnome-terminal libpam-gnome-keyring \
  libproxy1-plugin-gsettingslibproxy1-plugin-networkmanager network-manager-gnome \
  network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome ttf-ubuntu-font-family xdg-utils
  ```
- Some recommended packages for unity (`apt-cache depends unity` to see complete list):

  ```
  sudo apt-get install unity-control-center unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files \
  indicator-session indicator-power indicator-keyboard indicator-datetime \
  indicator-sound indicator-application indicator-appmenu hud
  ```